# Second Fundamental Form of Hypersurface

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Suppose we have a a graph of *two* functions in 3D, which I suppose can be called a 3D surface in 5D (?), via:
$$
\Pi = \{ t(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,f(x,y,z),g(x,y,z))\,|\, x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^3 \}
$$
I want to compute the second fundamental form (in $x,y,z$ coordinates).
Note that my actual goal is to compute the principal and mean curvatures.

The tangent (column) vectors can be $t_x=\partial_x t, t_y=\partial_y t, t_z=\partial_z t$.
Let $J$ be the Jacobian (i.e. $J=[t_x,t_y,t_z]$).

Here is what is confusing me.

Normally, I would compute (for these coordinates) the second fundamental form via $S_{ij}=\partial_i n \cdot t_j$. But here $\text{null}(J^T)$ is 2D! So there are two linearly independent fields of normal vectors (which makes sense, intuitively). 
Every reference I look at computes $S$ using a field of normals $n$. What do I do when I have two fields, $n_1$ and $n_2$? Can I just choose one?

Thanks!

Comment: $f(x,y,z)$ is actually a 4D object, a hypersurface in 5D yes

Comment: @Triatticus are you saying $\Pi$ is a 4D surface in 5D? I figured it was 3D because there are only 3 independent variables.

Comment: It has dimension $3$. Speaking loosely,    you can compute the mean curvature vector as $(1/3)({\rm II}(e_1)+{\rm II}(e_2)+{\rm II}(e_3)) $, where the $e_i$ form an orthonormal basis of the tangent space. Given any normal vector $N$, you can look at associated  principal directions. And if $\{N_1,N_2\}$ is an orthonormal basis of the normal space, you can compute a sort of Gaussian curvature as $K =(1/2)(\det dN_1+\det dN_2)$, which independs of the choice of $N_1$ and $N_2$ perhaps modulo sign (orientation and such).

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks for that! My issue is that I do not know how to compute $II(v)$ though. How can I compute the components of $II$, so that I can calculate the shape operator and its eigenvalues?

Comment: ${\rm II}(e_i)$ is the normal component of $\nabla_{e_i}e_i$

Comment: You'll have one shape for each normal. The second fundamental form takes a tangent vector and gives a normal one. It does not have eigenvalues and such, since it is not a linear operator. You can do that to ${\rm II}_N(v) = \langle {\rm II}(v),N\rangle$, though (for each $N$)

Comment: Yes. What we can show is that that analogue of the Gaussian curvature does not depend on $N_1$ and $N_2$, but I think that's as far as it goes

Comment: @IvoTerek Thank you, that is very enlightening. So I would then have two sets of principal curvatures, one per shape operator? Also, if I may ask, do you know a resource I can read about this particular situation? (Apologies for the abundance of questions.)

Comment: You actually have one set of principal directions for each shape. I'm sorry, no specific refrence comes to mind, but looking up books in Riemannian Geometry seems the way to go.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115672/is-there-a-notion-of-mean-curvature-for-general-submanifolds) for reference.