# Can we define the shape operator in four dimensions or higher?

Tags: differential-geometry

In three dimensions, we have the notion of the curvature of a curve as a positive real number, and it's pointed out sometimes that if the curve is limited to two dimensions, the curvature can be signed. Or, reasoning backwards, curvature is well defined at each point of a 1d curve in 2d space as a 1x1 linear operator, but when we embed a 1d curve in a higher dimension space, curvature "degenerates" to merely being a positive real number.

For a 2d surface embedded in 3d space, we have the shape operator (the differential of the Gauss map), a 2x2 linear operator, which seems to be the generalization of curvature to surfaces. Does something similar happen if I try to embed a 2d surface in 4d space? Do I somehow lose the ability to define the shape operator as an actual linear operator, and it collapses to some simpler kind of object?

Comment: In three dimensions, a regular surface has a unique normal line at each point, so (locally, at least) there is a smooth mapping to the unit sphere by choosing a continuous unit normal field. Have you considered what the normal space to a surface in four-dimensional space looks like...? :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Two dimensional? But that doesn't stop us from defining a notion of curvature for curves in 3d space. Can we do something similar in 4d space?

Comment: In higher codimension the Gauss map of a surface $\Sigma \to \mathbb R^n$ takes values in a Grassmannian $G(2,n)$. You should be able to get a generalised shape operator $T\Sigma \to T^* \Sigma \otimes N \Sigma$ by differentiating this. The result will be dual to the second fundamental form $T \Sigma \otimes T \Sigma \to N \Sigma$, which is more commonly used.

Comment: This is actually very similar to  [my own previous question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188423/second-fundamental-form-of-hypersurface), I think :) Basically, you have co-dimension 2, so now you have *two* shape operators (two independent normal vectors at a point).